# Auto fill array using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofill

I need to create mini arrays given start/end numbers and then merge them into one array.

Example:

- Array1: start:2 end:6
- Array2: start:12 end:15
- Array3: start:20 end:23
- Final array:
  2,3,4,5,6,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23

The start and end numbers are user input from a form.

How do I auto fill the array?

```vb
ws.Range("A1") = start_num
'stop at last number
ws.Range("A1").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
  Step:=1, Stop:=last_num, Trend:=False
```

This auto fills one start-end number in column A but I would rather store data in arrays and only have the final array shown on the spreadsheet.

Comment: A `For` loop is one approach.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically populate an array with a disiparate set of ranges I would use a sub and an ArrayList.  To get an arraylist you either need to add a reference to mscorlib, or use create object e.g. CreateObject("ArrayList")

At Module Level

```
Public myAL as ArrayList

' or Public myAL as Object

Public sub Fill(byval ipStart as long, byval ipEnd as Long)
    If myAL is nothing then
      set myAL = new ArrayList
      ' or Set myAL = CreateObject("Arraylist")
    end if

    Dim myIndex as long
    for myIndex = ipStart to ipEnd
        myAL.add myIndex
    next
end sub
```

You'd then use it as follows

```
Fill 2,6
Fill 12,15
Fill 20, 23

Dim myArray as variant
myArray = myAL.ToArray
```

Please note that the ArrayList object doesn't provide any intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution solely in VBA, is via some sort of a builder class.

```
Dim al As ArrayList
Set al = New ArrayList

'array
Dim arr As Variant
arr = al.Join(2, 6).Join(12, 15).Join(20, 23).ToArray()

'string
Dim s As String
s = al.Join(2, 6).Join(12, 15).Join(20, 23).ToString()

'or simply once filled
s = al.ToString()

Debug.Print s
'2,3,4,5,6,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23
```

---

`ArrayList` class:

```
Option Explicit
Private m_collection As Collection

Public Function Join(ByVal lower As Long, ByVal upper As Long) As ArrayList
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lower To upper
        m_collection.Add i
    Next
    
    Set Join = Me
End Function

Public Function ToArray() As Variant
    
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(m_collection.Count - 1)
    
    'Collection index statrts at 1.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To m_collection.Count
        arr(i - 1) = m_collection(i)
    Next
    
    ToArray = arr
End Function

Public Function ToString(Optional ByVal delimiter As String = ",") As String
    ToString = VBA.Join(ToArray(), delimiter)
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_collection = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_collection = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

You could set the `VB_PredeclaredId` to true to have a single instance, but you will need to clear the collection after each fill to avoid duplicates.